# Convert float latitude and longitude into geography

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to convert float latitude and longitude values into geography type value? I have `@lat` and `@lon` variables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With case statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN ((@Latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (@Longitude IS NOT NULL))
    THEN geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)
    ELSE NULL           
END
```

or a variant with if:

```
 DECLARE @Location geography = NULL
 IF (@Latitude IS NOT NULL AND @Longitude IS NOT NULL)
    SET @Location = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution by myself:

```
geography::STPointFromText(
    'POINT(' + CAST(@lon AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@lat AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
```

Comment: I don't like this. First you cast to varchar, then string concatenation and then conversion to point.

Comment: @Anderson, any alternatives?

Comment: Yes. (filler to fill 15 characters)

Comment: @Anderson thank you response. It's quite old task that I had about a year ago so currently I have no reason to back to it and check your solution. Nevertheless I'll mark your answer as "correct" if it collects some upvotes.